# CMD check if registry key exist

Tags: batch-file, cmd

I have multiple registry keys called

- O365BusinessRetail - en-us
- O365BusinessRetail - de-de
- ... and so on for many languages

I want to check if the registry keys exist or not. But this command will not work "Registry key could not be found"

```
reg query "HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\O365BusinessRetail*"

IF %ERRORLEVEL% == 1 exit 1
If %ERRORLEVEL% == 0 exit 0
```

I also tried

```
reg query "HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall" /v ? | findstr /C "O365BusinessRetail*"

IF %ERRORLEVEL% == 1 exit 1
If %ERRORLEVEL% == 0 exit 0
```

However with Powershell it works but I can't use it because Powershell is blocked on our side

```
if (Test-Path -Path registry::HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\O365BusinessRetail*) {
  exit 1  # same as: Write-Output 1
}
else {
  exit 0  # same as: Write-Output 0
}
```

What is the best way to do that in CMD?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your submitted code should look like this:

```bash
@SystemRoot%\System32\reg.exe Query "HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall" /F "O365BusinessRetail*" /K 1>NUL 2>&1
@Exit %Errorlevel%
```

If one or more subkeys beginning with the string `O365BusinessRetail` exist, the script will exit with the `0` error code. If none exist, it will exit with a `1` error code.

*Please also note that it is possible that the applications are registered under another uninstall key branch or root key.*